# Why is my Java UDP server listener not successfully listening to a UDP server if the UDP server starts after my code?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a thread that is listening to a UDP server. It works well unless (1) the UDP server is started after my application, or (2) the UDP server is restarted while my application is running. In either of those cases, my listener will not connect to the server any more.

It seems stuck in the awaitRequests() method, but I am not for sure.

Where is the code breaking?

```
package myPackage;

public class UDPServerListener implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean run = true;

    private byte[] receiveBuffer;
    private int receiveBufferSize;
    private InetSocketAddress myInetSocketAddress;
    private DatagramSocket myDatagramSocket;
    private DatagramPacket myDatagramPacket;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create and bind a new DatagramSocket
            myDatagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
            myInetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(123456);
            myDatagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            myDatagramSocket.bind(myInetSocketAddress);

            // Set-up the receive buffer
            receiveBuffer = new byte[2047];
            myDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer, 2047);

            awaitRequests(myDatagramSocket, myDatagramPacket);

        } catch (SocketException se) {
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }

    private void awaitRequests(DatagramSocket myDatagramSocket, DatagramPacket myDatagramPacket) throws SocketException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        int maxRetries = 5;

        while (run){
            try {
                myDatagramSocket.receive(myDatagramPacket);
                byte[] data = myDatagramPacket.getData();

                maxRetries = 5;

                process(data);

            } catch (SocketException se){
                maxRetries--;
                if(maxRetries == 0) throw se;
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
                reconnect(myDatagramSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    private void process(byte[] data) throws SocketException {
        receiveBufferSize = myDatagramPacket.getLength();
        // Do stuff with the received data ...
        myDatagramPacket.setLength(2047);
    }

    private void reconnect(DatagramSocket myDatagramSocket) throws SocketException{
        myDatagramSocket.bind(myInetSocketAddress);
    }

    public boolean isRun() {
        return run;
    }

    public void setRun(boolean run) {
        this.run = run;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

myInetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(123456);

is invalid, the max port number is 65535, so you're creating an invalid address.

I would go for something more like this:

```
public class TestUdp {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        boolean run = true;
        DatagramSocket sock = null;
        try {
            sock = new DatagramSocket(50001);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        byte[] buff = new byte[2000];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);

        while (run) {
            try {
                sock.receive(dp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            dp.getData();
            System.out.println("Received: " + dp.getLength() + " bytes");
        }

    }
}
```

The DatagramSocket constructor already binds to the port and there is no need to do "reconnect()" like you did, as UDP si not connected, once you have a process bound to a UDP port, it's there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work. It still doesn't start receiving any data from the UDP server once the server is restarted. I am binding to a specific port, that Is why I am using DatagramSocket.bind(). Also, FYI, I just used "123456" as a placeholder here in my StackOverflow post.

Comment: Please don't use placeholders, show *real* code. And please show the latest code that is not working for you.

Comment: @Brian is your server poorly implemented? I guarantee you the code works perfectly.

Comment: @sahel Possibly .... I am checking on that to find out for myself. I'll update when I find out.

Comment: @Brian, you should try with a command like: "nc -u IP PORT" and then type some data in, this way you will test if the receiver works. By doing: "nc -l -u -p PORT" you can test if the server (sender) works

Comment: @sahel The issue is that the server requires prodding (a specific UDP message) before it will talk with you. The DatagramSocket is blocking my listener while it is listening for the server to talk with sock.receive(dp). However, I don't know if I need to prod the server because my listener is blocked.

Comment: @Brian in short words, you need to send a udp packet to the server before it starts sending anything? You need to call socket.send(dgaramPacket) where dparamPacket is DatagramPacket with the right data in it.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the exact problem. Otherwise I can't really help you. Can you paste the server-side code too?

Comment: @sahel Unfortunately the server is out of my control.

Comment: @Brian, You should at least describe how it works, than I can maybe help you.

Comment: @sahel The server is a UDP server. It is subscription based. In order for the server to talk with a client, the client has to subscribe to the server's services. If the client does not subscribe, the server never talks to the client. Once the client subscribes, the server sends periodic heartbeats to the client to let the client know the server is still up. The client has to send it's listening port to the server in periodic heartbeats. My issue is trying to figure out what to do if the server is not running when my client starts, or if the server restarts while my client is running.